IPv4 packets coming from the VPN interface are sent back correctly, but not IPv6
I have a Wireguard VPN set up to forward packets (with iptables) received on a VPS to a server, which works great. However, the automatic configuration of the eno2 interface (of the server) by Debian creates IP routes, one of those is x:x:x:x::/64 dev eno2, which is the local network on which the server is.
This creates unwanted behavior, because when I (from the local network) send packets to the server through the VPS (this means the server will receive the packets on interface wg0), the server replies on the local network (interface eno2), because the source IPv6 address is the same on the Internet and on the local network, and therefore matches the route x:x:x:x::/64 dev eno2, even though non-local IPv6 traffic gets sent through wg0. And it responds with an IP address the computer from which I sent the packets does not know because I have set up NAT with Wireguard.
As written in the title this does not occur with IPv4, because it uses NAT, so the source IP address does not match 192.168.1.0/24 dev eno2.
I can always connect directly to the server without going through the VPS, or connect with the link-local addresses fe80::/10 when I need to and override the automatically configured route with one that has lower metric and higher preference (e.g. x:x:x:x::/64 dev wg0 metric 200 pref high) to keep the automatic configuration made by Debian, except this route. But this does not take into consideration that the network prefix may change. I was also able to make it work by adding a SNAT rule with iptables from the VPS but this breaks services that need the source IP address (e.g. SPF).
Is there a nicer solution to the problem? Perhaps by adding a route which sends back packets from wg0 to wg0, and making this route take priority over the x:x:x:x::/64 dev eno2 route, so that I can still access the server on my local network with its public IPv6 address?

the source IPv6 address is the same on the Internet and on the local network, and therefore matches the route x:x:x:x::/64 dev eno2 Honestly I couldn't see what you mean at all. First of all, it sounds like both the "client" and the "server" are connected to the "VPS" through WG, right? (Or is the "server" and the "VPS" in the same local network?) Why would the local subnet route on the server matches / covers the VPN IP of the "client" when the VPN network (is supposed to) use a different subnet/prefix?

@TomYan I am sorry if I worded that poorly. The client is not on the VPN, I only use the VPN to make the VPS forward packets to the server, so it seems like you are sending packets to the VPS, a sort of reverse proxy I believe. The client is on the same local network as the server, so when the server tries to route back packets, it sees that the client is on the same network and sends packets through the Ethernet interface, not the VPN one, because of the route I've mentioned.

Ah, I see how they are interconnected now, I think. Well, you'll need policy routing on the server for this. Have a route table that consists of a default route with the wg interface as the route interface, then use an ip rule to have it looked up conditionally. In many cases you can use the replying source address (when it is the VPN IP) as the match. In some cases you may need to resort to "connmark".

But because the default "trick" wg-quick leverage for default routes in AllowedIPs= doesn't suit you need, you would probably want to set Table= to a number (of your choice) and deal with ip rule yourself (in PostUp= maybe).

@TomYan ah, of course! Policy routing with the VPN IP works just how I want it to, how  embarrassing that I did not think about doing this. Thank you for your help, I am now going to answer my own question with what worked for me.

IPv6 can have multiple network addresses on a single interface. You could even use ULA addressing for traffic you never want on the public Internet.

@RonMaupin I see, thank you for the information.

I may have not expressed myself very well, so just to make things clear: I am using the VPS as a reverse proxy to access my server. The client from which I want to access the server is not on the VPN, but it is on the same local network as the server, so this was the problem:
wg0 2001::1 > fdea:0335:40b8::2
eno2 fdea:0335:40b8::2 > 2001::1

While I expected:
wg0 2001::1 > fdea:0335:40b8::2
wg0 fdea:0335:40b8::2 > 2001::1

2001::1 is the IPv6 address of the client, fdea:0335:40b8::2 is the IPv6 address of the server within the VPN.

Because I am using ULAs on the VPN, I can route packets based on the source address (check if it is an address of the VPN).
The server has an IPv6 address on the local network, say x:x:x:x::2, and an address on the VPN, say fdea:0335:40b8::2.
Because the VPS forwards packets to the server through the VPN by changing the IP destination to fdea:0335:40b8::2, the server will reply with this IPv6 address. With this information I can do the following:
ip -6 rule add from fdea:0335:40b8::2/128 table 2
ip -6 route add default dev wg0 table 2

This solves the problem because fdea:0335:40b8::2/128 is more specific than the aforementioned route, x:x:x:x::/64, and therefore takes priority. I can then add the above commands in the wg0 configuration file with PostUp= and PreDown=, so that they are only active when necessary.
Thanks to everyone who helped, please tell me if any of this needs more clarification or anything to make this question and answer more exploitable.

Assign the VPN different addresses outside the server's existing nets. Especially different from any on link  /64s going through say an Ethernet.
A good hosting provider will route multiple never-used /64s to your host on request, say a /56. You then can set an entire /64 for VPN addresses.  As public IP addresses, they can access the internet, if allowed by firewalls.
A less good hosting provider will only provide additional on link prefixes. Their gateway will assume it can do NDP over Ethernet when really it needs to be routed through your server via wg. Do your own NDP replies as a hack to make this work, like with ndpresponder program.
If internet access is not required, consider generating ULA addresses for the purpose of VPN addresses. Visit here for a ULA prefix just for you.
The address space is so large every person on the planet could be issued thousands of /48, vastly bigger, and maybe then the utilization would be noticeable. New subnets for every purpose is the simpler IPv6 way of doing things.

Thank you for answering my question. But even if I make a subnet for the VPN, the source IPv6 address will still be from the local network on which my server is, except if I also put in the VPN the computer from which I send the packets (maybe this is what you meant). In addition, I believe my hosting provider gives me only one IPv6 address for my VPS, so I am using ULAs.

I also want to comment that I am using the VPS as a reverse proxy, in case I have not explained very well what I am trying to achieve. Using it this way works for every host outside the local network because it does not try to route it through the Ethernet interface.

I had qualified my answer with something outside the existing networks, in other words not the subnets on the existing interface. Complain to the provider about inadequate address space.  A VPN network is an obvious use for another /64.

I understand now, this is not what I was trying to achieve, but it is useful information nevertheless, I will keep it in mind.
